# 2016 Toyota Corolla L Keyless Entry / Remote lock unlock

Tags: toyota, corolla

I just purchased a 2016 Corolla L. Love the car! I recently had a remote start/keyless entry system installed. (it's the scytek a4.2w - linked [here](https://scytek.net/product/a4-2w/)) The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get the keyless entry lock/unlock to work when the car is not on. The link to the kit that I have installed is below. If I use the remote start, I can lock and unlock the doors when the car is running. If the car is not running, the lock/unlock feature does not work on either of the remotes. I know that the 2016 Corolla L does NOT come stock with keyless entry. Does that have something to do with why the keyless entry only works while the car runs? I'm just confused because the car does have power locks that work when the car is off... If there's a part I would need to purchase or something I'd need to do. ANY help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any of schematics, it would seem to me you've hooked the power wrong to it, or rather, you may have *hooked up the wrong kind of power*. I'm assuming it would need some kind of power attached to it in order to work. If you've attached that power lead from an ignition sourced power lead (one which is only on when the ignition is on), it won't have power when the car is off and then won't know when to start things up. Check to ensure you have it attached to an "always on" or battery power source. I'm betting this will be your problem and will solve your issue once fixed.